# Выполнять функцию после изменения стиля элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Есть изображение с шириной width 300px. С помощью JavaScript я изменяю размер, с width 300px на 500px, свойством transition указываю скорость 5s. После чего, когда width достигает 500px - нужно вызывать функцию. Вопрос, как это сделать? Может быть while (true) который будет постоянно проверять не равняется ли width 500px. Если равняется - прямо там вызывать функцию. Благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: добавьте свой код,посмотрим что можно сделать

Answer (score 4):

Используйте событие `transitionend`

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button'),
    paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
    
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  paragraph.style.width = '500px';
})

paragraph.addEventListener('transitionend',function(e){
  if(e.propertyName = 'width'){//если изменённое свойство - ширина
    console.log('переход завершён. Свойство: '+e.propertyName);
  }  
})
```

```css
p{
  transition: all 5s linear;
  width: 300px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<p>as kjas dghaskjd gasghfkj ahgfj hakjgsdkjagdhjsf hkahjsdkljas</p>
<button>Запустить transition</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А если у меня стиль на элементе меняется и ширина и высота, а функцию по окончанию нужно вызывать только при изменении ширины?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда , используйте свойство `propertyName` для события